# How to map ranges to values?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm actually wondering what is a best way to assign letter to a range properly in C++.

For example, we have that scale:

[image]

We can do assignment in simplest way:

```
if(a < 40)
  return 'T';
else if(a < 55)
  return 'D';
else if(a < 70)
  return 'P';
else if(a < 80)
  return 'A';
else if(a < 90)
  return 'E';
else if(a <= 100)
  return 'O';
```

However, do you have some better ideas to make this?

And what when we have bigger numbers and more letters (I think that if statements can be still annoying...)? Or what if there are free spaces between ranges, e.g. 30-40 45-55 60-70?

Comment: It's either this or a lookup table, for only 6 records this approach seems to be okay though. Might want to refactor the magic numbers though

Comment: You don't have to AND the next condition with the negation of the previous one. There's `else`, which again, does not have to be there, since there's `return`.

Comment: @LogicStuff Perhaps for clearity.

Comment: You're right @LogicStuff, I'll edit my code

Comment: But what if there are free spaces between ranges, e.g. 30-40 45-55 60-70, it back to previous version of my code. I wonder if there can be used a map in some smart way.

Comment: How do you define _best way_? Is it the fastest execution, shortest code in C++, shortest machine code, …?

Comment: Good question, I define it as shortest readable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple arrays for sorted ranges and outputs

```
char getGrade (int grade) {
    int upper[] = { 40, 55, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    int lower[] = { 0, 40, 55, 70, 80, 90 };
    char grades[] = { 'T', 'D', 'P', 'A', 'E', 'O' };

    for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++) 
        if ((grade< upper[i]) && (grade >= lower[i]))               
            return grades[i];
    return 'X'; // no grade assigned
}
```

Edit: I'm adding interesting implementation with `struct` and `std::find_if` suggested by @YSC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Data{ int lower; int upper; char grade; };

char getGrade (int grade, std::vector<Data> data) {
    auto it = std::find_if(
            data.begin(),
            data.end(), 
            [&grade](Data d) { return (d.lower<= grade) && (d.upper > grade); }
           );
    if (it == data.end())
        return 'X'; // not found
    else
        return it->grade;
}

int main () {
    const std::vector<Data> myData = { { 0, 40, 'T'} , { 40, 55, 'D'}, {55, 70, 'P'}, {70, 80, 'A'}, {80, 90, 'E'}, {90, 101, 'O'} };
    std::cout << getGrade(20, myData) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks, but look at bottom of my question at last added requirement, how you can change this code to respect free gaps?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can just add another array for lower bounds.

Comment: For an easier reading, you could aggregate your arrays into an array of `struct def { int lower; int upper; char grade; } = { { 0, 40, 'T'}, ... };`.

Comment: It's seems easy to enlarge and pretty simple. Best answer for me.

Comment: Also, you could use `std::find_if` instead of the for+if loop.

Comment: Good points @YSC. Actually you could just write a proper class with constructor, getter for the grade and binary search for the right interval...

Answer (score 3):

A general solution applicable in almost every case is to define in a self-describing way the bounds for each notation and then find the appropriate value with [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

char grade(int a)
{
    constexpr std::pair<int, char> bounds[] = {
        { 39,  'T' },
        { 54,  'D' },
        { 69,  'P' },
        { 79,  'A' },
        { 89,  'E' },
        { 99,  'O' },
        { 100, '\0' },
    };

    return std::lower_bound(begin(bounds),end(bounds),std::make_pair(a, '\0'))->second;
}
```

[Test (demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97c61ac51d30aa71):

```
grade(39): T
grade(40): D
grade(54): D
grade(55): P
grade(69): P
grade(70): A
grade(79): A
grade(80): E
grade(89): E
grade(90): O
grade(99): O
grade(100):
```

---

Another solution for this specific problem could be, since numbers involved here are small, to use a simple lookup table:

```
static const char map[] =
    "............" // make 40 of them
    "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT" // 40..54
    "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" // 55..69
    // etc
    ;

return map[a];
```

Finally, an alternative for larger or negative numbers or sparser ranges is to use an actual `std::map`:

```
#include <map>
static const std::map<int, char> map = {
    { 40, 'T' },
    { 41, 'T' },
    // ...
    { 100, 'O' }
};
return map.at(a);
```

Comment: What about `std::lower_bound` on a set of \*nodes\*?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` is new thing for me, nice

Comment: @LogicStuff I've added your suggestion to my answer. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: This answer would be improved by moving the non-allocating, self-documenting, near maximally efficient answer first; the lower_bound one.  (The table will be faster admittedly, but it sucks in every other way)  Also question included "free gaps", which is a trivial change to this answer to handle.

Comment: and `std::map` also has a `lower_bound` member

Answer (score 3):

This is a C++14 answer.  Everything can be translated to C++11, just less pretty.

```
template<class F, class Base=std::less<>>
auto order_by( F&& f, Base&& b={} ) {
  return
    [f=std::forward<F>(f), b = std::forward<Base>(b)]
    (auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
    ->bool
    {
      return b( f(lhs), f(rhs) );
    };
}
```

`order_by` takes a projection and optionally a comparison function object, and returns a comparison function object that applies the projection then either `std::less<>` or the comparison function object.

This is useful when sorting or searching, as C++ algorithms require comparison function objects, while projections are easy to write.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct binary_overload_t:A,B{
  using A::operator();
  using B::operator();
  binary_overload_t( A a, B b ):A(std::move(a)), B(std::move(b)) {}
};
template<class A, class B>
binary_overload_t< A, B >
binary_overload( A a, B b ) {
  return { std::move(a), std::move(b) };
}
```

`binary_overload` lets you overload function objects.

```
template<class T>
struct valid_range_t {
  T start, finish;
};
```

This represents a valid range.  I could just use `std::pair`, but I prefer types with meaning.

```
template<class T, class V>
struct ranged_value_t {
  valid_range_t<T> range;
  V value;
};
template<class T, class It>
auto find_value( It begin, It end, T const& target )
-> decltype(std::addressof( begin->value ))
{
  // project target into target
  // and a ranged value onto the lower end of the range
  auto projection = binary_overload(
    []( auto const& ranged )->T const& {
      return ranged.range.finish;
    },
    []( T const& t )->T const& {
      return t;
    }
  );
  // 
  auto it = std::upper_bound( begin, end,
    target,
    order_by( projection )
  );
  if (it == end) return nullptr;
  if (target < it->range.start) return nullptr;
  return std::addressof( it->value );
}
```

Now `find_value` takes a pair of iterators to `ranged_value_t` type structures arranged with non-overlapping ranges.

It then return a pointer to the entry of the first (and hence only) value whose (half open) range contains `target`.

```
ranged_value_t<int, char> table[]={
  {{0,40}, 'T'},
  {{41,55}, 'D'},
  {{56,70}, 'P'},
  {{71,80}, 'A'},
  {{81,90}, 'E'},
  {{91,101}, 'O'}
};

auto* ptr = find_value( std::begin(table), std::end(table), 83 );
if (ptr) std::cout << *ptr << "\n"; else std::cout << "nullptr\n";
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4062d69139f4e7c5).

The advantages of this answer over alternatives:

- We don't create needless value objects.  If the value objects are expensive, large, or non-trivially constructible, this matters.
- The syntax to create a table is simple
- Tables can be in nearly any format.  You can parse them from a file; the `find_value` function just takes iterators (and prefers them to be random access).
- We could augment with permitting the lower bound to be omitted.  We'd have to add a flag to `valid_range_t` (or use an optional) and consume it in `find_value` when we check `s`, and add constructors to `valid_range_t` to make it easy to use.

Augmenting it to support both half-open and closed intervals would take a bit of work.  I'd be tempted to hack it into `find_value` as a second check.

Overlapping intervals also takes a bit of work.  I'd do a lower_bound on start (`s`) and an upper_bound on finish (`f`).

I find this kind of stuff is best suited by data-driven design; hardcoding this in C++ code is a bad plan.  Instead, you consume configuration, and you write your code to validate and be driven by that configuration.

Comment: My favorite types of overkill

Comment: If you need more than one hour to conceive a lookup table, you'll need two to maintain it later and the new guy hired last week will hate you at some point. Most of the time, simple & clumsy is better than clever & beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be fancy and like to have an easily expansible list then you can use a lookup table and just loop through it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

char returnGrade(int a)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> chars = {
        std::make_pair('T', 40),
        std::make_pair('D', 55),
        std::make_pair('P', 70),
        std::make_pair('A', 80),
        std::make_pair('E', 90),
        std::make_pair('O', 100)
    };
    for(auto itr = chars.begin(); itr != chars.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(a < itr->second)
          return itr->first;
    }
    //return the last one if we passed the loop.
    return chars.back().first;
}

int main() {
    //test it..
    std::cout << returnGrade(20) << " " << returnGrade(45) << " " << returnGrade(90)  << " " << returnGrade(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you shouldn't have that lookup table local to the function but you get the idea.

Comment: But what if there are free spaces between ranges, e.g. 30-40 45-55 60-70, it back to previous version of my code. I wonder if there can be used a map in some smart way.

Comment: @BartekPL Presumably you'd need to return _something_ for the gaps (e.g. 41..44), so add the _something_ as an element of the map (`std::make_pair(_something_, 41)`).

Comment: @TripeHound, yes I know that way, and it seems good option for this code

Comment: Why use dynamic allocation?

Comment: @Yakk As an example to create flexibility (maybe lookup table runtime alterations). If that won't happen then `std::array` will do just fine yeah.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you can use simple `array` and simple `for`

```
int array[ 8 ]  = { 0,  40,  55,   70,  80,  90, 100,  101 };
char score[ 7 ] = {  'T', 'D',  'P', 'A', 'E', 'O', 'O' };

int input = 50;
for( int index = 0; index < 8; ++index ){
    if( input < array[ index ] ){
        std::cout << score[ index - 1 ];  // D
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE**

1. Instead of `std:cout` you can use `return`
2. the extra `O` and `101` just used for also match 100 itself.

Comment: It seems worse version of Robert Eckhaus answer

Comment: @BartekPL where is the problem?

Comment: You just not include free gaps requirement in your answer, however for table from my question it is perfect answer :)